# VS Code View In Browser Issue

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried using the extension View In Browser. But after the installation the instructions are: 
1. Open the command list (Press F1 or Ctrl + Shift + P)
 2. Select View In Browser
 When I do that I get a warning:"no active text editor!" I don't know I am doing wrong...
 Also when I try to Configure Task Runner, I get: "Tasks are only available on a workspace folder."

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue "Tasks are only available on a workspace folder" when no folder was open under Explorer. Open Explorer (Ctrl+Shift+E) and make sure you have open folder.

Answer (score -2):

may be you have not created a file or a folder. Before trying that open a new folder and add a new file